# Sending private message to facebook friend (API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently creating an app that generates a unique link that can be sent to a friend on facebook.

I want to be able to send the link to a specific person from a users friends list. Is this possible? I'm currently using the fb javascript api but can't seem to find any such functionality but posting on ones wall.

Thanks

Comment: Use the Send dialog